# android reminder

Tags: java, android

I'm new on android programming and i'm working on reminder application. now, i've done storing all information including date and time into SQLlite database. my question is how do i match alarm that stored in database with current time on android

Answer (score 1):

query the data base compare with calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
long time2=   c.getTimeInMillis();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
  c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);   
   long time3=   c.getTimeInMillis();
   if(time>time2){
 //Logic
 if(time>time3){
     //Logic
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

or count down the seconds instead of ever using calender or relative phone time.. did a similar app myself and it seems to reduce variabality due to phone time being off or reset etc...